# Compile Build and c file on Windows

Tags: c, windows, build

I have a directory that has the following files

1. Build
2. asc2uni.c
3. asc2uni.1

I have to compile it, but the problem is I don't know how what is the compiler to use for this format and how to do it. Any ideas?

**Edit: I am trying to compile this on Windows XP.**

Edit 2: The Build file content:

```
cc -I../Modules -O -o asc2uni asc2uni.c ../Modules/Lib.a
```

Comment: So the build script looks like a gcc style script. Note that it references a "Modules" subdirectory you will need for linking.

Comment: Can you explain why you wantv to compile this project? There may be a freely downloadable Windows executable that does the same thing.

Comment: from what you posted you need the content of the folder Modules (it is added to your include path) and also it contains the lib.a library which you probably need. Do you have that folder ? Anyway you need to follow one of the advices given in the answers below and download a C compiler before you can  continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest to use a MinGW variant.

I used [DCC+](http://dcplusplus.sourceforge.net/) in the past a lot. But you may try Code::Blocks (and make sure to use version which includes the MinGW Compiler).

Another thing you could do is to install [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and learn how to use all those cool developer tools in a linux environment. Which would also help you to get to read this name.1 file (which is a unix-man file)

Answer (score 2):

If they're graphical applications, your most likely going to need Visual C++ from Microsoft.

If, as I suspect, they're simple command-line applications (for ASCII/Unicode conversion), get a hold of one of the free command-line compilers. [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (Minimalist GNU for Windows) is one option but I always steer people towards [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) since, other than a build environment, it offers a slew of other things which come in really handy.

The `Build` file may well be the script which is supposed to build the code for you in which case its contents would be a great help (to you and us) in figuring out which tools you actually need.

Comment: Visual Studio Express is free, downloads prety quick

Comment: But I believe that the gui part in VSE C++ is not available.

Comment: That's not right, @Antonio, it may be missing some "enterprise" features but it's quite capable of making GUI Windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

The asc2uni file name sounds like it is part of [Unitex](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~unitex/index.html), and if so notice that the newest version have combined asc2uni and uni2asc into one program called `convert`. So you might want to investigate if you want to switch to a newer version before investing too much energy into trying to compile something old. Also I see there are a windows installer binary available as well, maybe you even do not have to compile anything?

Anyhow, to compile the file with the gcc compiler run

```
gcc -o asc2uni asc2uni.c
```

The file `asc2uni.1` sound like a manual file and does not need to be compiled, just installed. If you want to create a plain text version of it you can run

```
nroff -man asc2uni.1 | col -b > asc2uni.txt
```

For windows you can install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) where you can select to install gcc. There are also other ports of gcc (like [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/)), but probably any C compiler will do. Nroff and col are probably available in cygwin, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't come with a C compiler, so unless you install one you are out of luck. You can download a free C compiler from http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: If you'd like a pretty GUI to wrap around MinGW, which is command-line-based, check out Code::Blocks at http://www.codeblocks.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/download/#webInstall) is free, but is probably overkill for this little program. It does download and install pretty quickly, and is a good start for C/C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't currently have a C compiler, there are a number of options (the simplest is probably [mingw](http://http:www.mingw.org) as previously mentioned, or perhaps the free [Microsoft Visual Studio Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/).  A larger list can be found [here](http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp.shtml).

Or perhaps you already have Visual Studio and you want to know how to compile from the command line? If so, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639(VS.80).aspx) might help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's either console programs or windows program, try using codeblocks. To create the gui part of your program use ResEd http://www.oby.ro/rad_asm/resed/index.html
seems to have been discontinued but it's still a good editor